# Limitations of AMPL regarding large problems

Tags: ampl, gurobi

I'm about to employ my master thesis work soon towards optimization and I have some questions regarding the limitations of AMPL.

My tutors seems confident that AMPL will handle mostly all situations when a full license of for instance Gurobi solver is used (which my university has).

Yet, in most current thesis works I see that most people still use genetic algorithms and heuristics in other languages such as C, C#, Python etc. Is it preferable to implement your own heuristics in other languages or are there setting to provide this for you in AMPL provided that you have a full license of some solver?

Thus far my university has not had any practical problems when your own heuristics must be employed so it'll mean I have to study these alongside my last courses until the thesis work is about to start.

Thanks in advance! 
Cenderze

Comment: It mostly depends on the nature of the problems you have at hand. We would need more details to be able to write a half-sane answer. Apart from that, StackOverflow is about programming and software development questions and your question is off-topic here. However, you might get an answer at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I would like to provide as much information as possible! However I am to receive my actual problem definition come the 21st january. 

Thank you very much for that URL I was not aware of that web page. I thought stack overflow was somewhat like a fusion between programming and programming on a more conceptual plane, so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to implement heuristic methods using AMPL and many people do so using AMPL's scripting features or embedding it in other languages. This allows working on a higher level than the one provided by solver APIs and allows implementing methods that are solver-independent (AMPL provides access to many solvers).

Another possibility is implementing your method as an AMPL solver which also has its advantages as you won't need to worry about writing your own input methods or limitations of legacy formats such as MPS. [SSDSolver](https://github.com/ampl/ampl/tree/master/solvers/ssdsolver) is an example of this approach. It implements a cutting-plane algorithm for solving problems with second-order stochastic dominance constraints and uses another AMPL solver (e.g. `cplex`) to solve subproblems.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am not really sure what seperates those two possibilities, but this was merely a question of the possibility so your answer fits me perfectly! Thank you!